# Using of pointers in specific example

Tags: c++, pointers

I understand the idea of pointers and how they work.
But it's hard to understand in which example should I use them and where I can use variables.

**Disclaimer:** before creating this post I read a lot of answers on similar questions, but the answers were absctract, without concrete example.

Here is my example: Suppose I want to create a class `Course`, which constructor has a name and list of the students, that participate in this course.

Methods, which I want to implement:

1)to save the results for both test for each student and calculate the average pro Course and pro Student.

2)Methods to define id_number(matr_num) and name for each student.

In order to implement this class, I decided first of all to create class `Student`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
using namespace std;




class Student{
    private:
    string name;
    int matr_num;
    int test_1;
    int test_2;

    public:
    //Constructor:
    Student(string name,int matr_num,int test_1,int test_2);
    //Destructor:
    ~Student();
    //Copy constructor:
    Student(const Student& other);
    //Copy assingment:
    Student operator=(const Student& other);
    //Move constructor:
    Student(Student&& other);
    //Move assingment:
    Student operator=(Student&&other);  
    //Average of two tests:
    double test_average();
    //get name,matrikel_number, scores of test:
    string get_name() const ;
    double get_matr_num() const;
    double get_test_1() const ;
    double get_test_2() const ;

};

//Constructor
Student::Student(string name,int matr_num,int test_1,int test_2)
    :name{name},matr_num{matr_num},test_1{test_1},test_2{test_2}
        {
        }

//Destructor
Student::~Student(){
}

//Copy constructor:
Student::Student(const Student& other)
    :name{other.name},matr_num{other.matr_num},test_1{other.test_1},test_2{other.test_2}
        {

        }


//Copy assingment:
Student Student::operator=(const Student& other)
{
    name = other.name;
    matr_num = other.matr_num;
    test_1 = other.test_1;
    test_2 = other.test_2;

}   


//Move Constructor:
Student::Student(Student&& other)
    :name{other.name},matr_num{other.matr_num},test_1{other.test_1},test_2{other.test_2}
        {
            other.name = "";
            other.matr_num = 0;
            other.test_1 = 0;
            other.test_2 = 0;
        }       

//Move assingment:
Student Student::operator=(Student&& other)
{
    name = other.name;
    matr_num = other.matr_num;
    test_1 = other.test_1;
    test_2 = other.test_2;
    other.name = "";
    other.matr_num = 0;
    other.test_1 = 0;
    other.test_2 = 0;
}   

double Student::test_average(){
    return (test_1 + test_2)/2;
}


string Student::get_name()const{return name;}
double Student::get_matr_num()const{return matr_num;}
double Student::get_test_1()const{return test_1;}
double Student::get_test_2()const{return test_2;}
```

As you see, I did it without pointers and I will use it in order to create class `Course`

Here are the questions:

1)Should I use pointers instead of variables?

2)If yes/no, why?What are the advanteges of using pointers in this case?

Comment: 1) No. 2) As you've already noticed, you don't need them.

Comment: It's not necessary to provide all those copy and move constructors and operators and destructor in this case, since all of `Student`'s data members have proper value semantics, meaning the implicit versions will behave correctly.

Comment: Pointers usually don't behave as you would want them to with the implicit constructors, assignment operators, and destructor which is one of the many reasons why you should only use them when you need them.

Comment: Too broad. Can you avoid pointers in your simple program? Yes you can. Do you want us to review your code? Than the code goes to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . I am voting to close the question.

Comment: "But it's hard to understand in which example should I use them and where I can use variables." You should always avoid pointers unless you have to use them.

Comment: @Slava In many cases(for novice) it's really hard to understand in which situations should I use pointers. Theoretically I know when, but in practice...